# How To Fix: Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `INTERNET' has not been defined but instead it is?

Tags: glossaries

Cannot understand what's wrong with my glossary entries, since when I use one entry in the `\section` title I get the error above.
However the same entry is used few lines above without errors, so it must be defined and it is at least I can read it...
Here I link you to the tex project on ShareLatex so that you could understand what is wrong in, I hope, an easier way: [ShareLatex project](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59e7c22d34677045df5211e1). Another thing I can't understand is the fact that it complains abount the "INTERNET" entry, but it is defined as internet in lowercase.

Comment: If I remember correctly there's some statement in the `glossaries` documentation (yes, there is such a thing ;-)) that `\gls` etc. should *not* be used in `\section` titles. (I removed the [tag:latex3] tag since it is completely unrelated to the question)

Comment: you're right, I found hints about using the following code, and it works in the sections before the error's one:                  
\section{How big is the \texorpdfstring{\Gls{internet}}{internet}}

Comment: The `glossaries-extra` extension package has better handling for section headings described in [4. Entries in Sectioning Titles, Headers, Captions and Contents](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:headtitle)

Comment: a little working example would be very appreciated man, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post an MWE in your question instead of linking to an external site (especially if one has to have an account there to view your content).